# Can we hand over blank cheques to a bank when applying for any kinda loans?

Tags: india, loans, car, auto-loan

I applied for a 4 lakh car loan with HDFC Bank, but before they will approve it, they require four blank cheques with my signature. Is it safe to give the bank those cheques?

Comment: What reason did they give for wanting the cheques? If you can't make the payments because you're broke then I don't see how those cheques are going to be useful to them.